# Android app with RoboGuice 2.0 - How to inject a Singleton with the Application context

Tags: android, dependency-injection, guice, roboguice

I have a GameStateManager singleton that I want to have available to all of my activities. In particular I want it to listen for Events fired off with the EventManager using the Application Context instead of an individual Activity Context.

GameStateManager is marked with the singleton annotation

I tried to inject GameStateManager during Application.OnCreate 
(sorry, typed the below snippet from memory, not copied and pasted, so might be incorrect)

```
public void OnCreate(){
    GameStateManager gameStateManager = RoboGuice.InjectMembers(this.getApplicationContext(), new GameStateManager())

}
```

I thought that the instance of GameStateManager would be constructed with the application context and since it is annotated as a singleton would therefore be available later with the application context. What I noticed was that when I injected the GameStateManager into an activity, I actually got a new singleton tied to the activity context. So in essence I have 2 singletons :)

Any ideas on how to have a true 'singleton' that is connected to the Application context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you observe could be caused by lazy initialization (see https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes) in the development mode.

If you inject your manager at first in an activity, it is created lazily at that point. Since `Activity` satisfies for any `@Inject Context`, the activity is injected. This is actually very harmful, because if your manager is annotated with `@Singleton`, it lives longer than the activity and you basically just created a memory leak.

I found it more explicit to `@Inject` `Application` or `Activity` depending on what I expected to be injected where (`Activity` usually for `@ContextSingleton`'s, `Application` for plain `@Singleton`'s).

Answer (score 0):

Since **RoboGuice** is built under **Guice** you could try to use `@Singelton` annotation which guarantee one instance per `Injector`

Take a look to [example application](https://github.com/emmby/roboguice/blob/master/astroboy/src/main/java/org/roboguice/astroboy/controller/Astroboy.java)

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work. If I'm not mistaken, doesn't the ContextSingleton give you a singleton per context, which is actually the experience I am seeing with the Singleton as well

Comment: The javadoc says it should be singelton for context. Going to search more. So let delete this answer so far.

Comment: feel free to delete, I don't have that option

Comment: That is what I tried (using @Singleton). Maybe I don't understand what the "per Injector" means in an Android app.